# Issue with opening correct player's shop GUI in ui_screen_market method

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm currently working on a plugin that includes a marketplace feature where players can open a GUI to browse and purchase items from other players. I have a method called `ui_screen_market` that displays a list of player names as buttons, and when a player clicks on a button, it should open a new GUI with the items that the corresponding player is selling. However, I'm facing an issue where clicking on a username in the ui_screen_market GUI opens another person's screen instead of the expected player's shop GUI.

I have tried debugging the code and verifying the values being passed to the methods, but I couldn't find any obvious mistakes. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling the button clicks or accessing the player's data.

Expected behavior:

Clicking on a player's name in the ui_screen_market GUI should open a new GUI displaying the items that the corresponding player is selling.

Actual behavior:

Clicking on a player's name in the ui_screen_market GUI opens another person's shop GUI instead of the expected player's shop GUI.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/3Vffumk3

Method with issue:

```
public void ui_screen_market_create(Player player) {
    FloodgatePlayer floodgatePlayer = floodgateApi.getPlayer(player.getUniqueId());
    if (floodgatePlayer != null) {
        floodgatePlayer.sendForm(CustomForm.builder()
                .title("Centori UI / MARKET / CREATE")
                .input("Shop name")
                .toggle("Confirm shop creation")
                .validResultHandler(response -> {
                    player.sendMessage("Shop creation in progress...");
                    boolean toggleValue = response.asToggle(1);
                    String inputValue = response.asInput(0);
                    if (toggleValue) {
                        Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("CentoriUI23");
                        assert plugin != null;
                        File directory = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "bdata/" + floodgatePlayer.getUsername());
                        boolean exists = directory.exists();

                        if (exists) {
                            player.sendMessage("An error occurred. Your shop might already exist.");
                        } else {
                            if (directory.mkdirs()) {
                                File file = new File(directory, "shops.json");
                                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
                                    writer.write("{\n   'shop-name': '" + inputValue + "' \n }");
                                    writer.flush();
                                    player.sendMessage("Shop created with name: " + inputValue);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    player.sendMessage("Something went wrong while creating the shop. Please open a ticket in Discord.");
                                    System.err.println("Failed to write to file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                                }
                            } else {
                                player.sendMessage("Something went wrong while creating the directory. Please open a ticket in Discord.");
                                System.err.println("Failed to create the directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        player.sendMessage("Shop creation has been canceled");
                    }
                })
                .closedOrInvalidResultHandler(response -> {
                    player.sendMessage("Form closed or invalid");
                })
                .build());
    }
}
public void ui_screen_market(Player player) {
    FloodgatePlayer floodgatePlayer = floodgateApi.getPlayer(player.getUniqueId());
    if (floodgatePlayer != null) {
        List<String> shopNames = new ArrayList<>();

        Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("CentoriUI23");
        assert plugin != null;
        File bdataFolder = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "bdata");
        File[] shopDirectories = bdataFolder.listFiles();

        if (shopDirectories != null) {
            for (File directory : shopDirectories) {
                if (directory.isDirectory()) {
                    shopNames.add(directory.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        if (!shopNames.isEmpty()) {
            SimpleForm.Builder formBuilder = SimpleForm.builder()
                    .title("Centori UI / MARKET TEST")
                    .button("Go Back")
                    .button("Create shop")
                    .button("Delete shop")
                    .button("Add item to your shop")
                    .validResultHandler(response -> {
                        int clickedButtonId = response.getClickedButtonId();
                        if (clickedButtonId == 0) {
                            ui_screen_join_main(player);
                        } else if (clickedButtonId == 1) {
                            ui_screen_market_create(player);
                        } else if (clickedButtonId >= 3) {
                            String clickedShopName = shopNames.get(clickedButtonId - 3);
                            openPlayerItemsGUI(player, clickedShopName); // Updated method call
                        }
                    })
                    .closedOrInvalidResultHandler(response -> {
                        player.sendMessage("Form closed or invalid");
                    });

            for (String shopName : shopNames) {
                formBuilder.button(shopName);
            }

            floodgatePlayer.sendForm(formBuilder.build());
        } else {
            player.sendMessage("No shops found.");
        }
    }
}





public void ui_screen_market_add(Player player) {
    FloodgatePlayer floodgatePlayer = floodgateApi.getPlayer(player.getUniqueId());
    if (floodgatePlayer != null) {
        floodgatePlayer.sendForm(CustomForm.builder()
                .title("Centori UI / MARKET / ADD")
                        .input("Enter Price")
                        .slider("Amount to sell for price",1,64)
                        .toggle("I confirm that the item in my possession will not be returned to me. (the item in your hand)")
                .validResultHandler(response -> {
                    ItemStack heldItem = player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand();

                        if (heldItem.getType() != Material.AIR) {

                            Material heldMaterial = heldItem.getType();
                            String itemName = heldItem.getType().toString();
                            int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(response.asInput(0)));
                            int itemAmount = heldItem.getAmount();
                            if (itemAmount < response.asSlider(1)) {
                                player.sendMessage("You dont have enough of this item.");
                            } else {
                                JsonObject itemObject = new JsonObject();
                                itemObject.addProperty("price", itemPrice);
                                itemObject.addProperty("amount", itemAmount);
                                String itemDetails = itemObject.toString();
                                Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("");
                                player.getInventory().setItemInMainHand(null);
                            }

                        } else {
                            // The player is not holding any item or holding air
                            player.sendMessage("You are not holding anything.");
                        }
                })
                .closedOrInvalidResultHandler(response -> {
                    player.sendMessage("GUI closed, type /gui to reopen!");
                })
                .build());
    }
}






private void openPlayerItemsGUI(Player player, String playerName) {
    FloodgatePlayer floodgatePlayer = floodgateApi.getPlayer(player.getUniqueId());
    if (floodgatePlayer != null) {
        SimpleForm.Builder formBuilder = SimpleForm.builder()
                .title("Items for Sale by: " + playerName)
                .validResultHandler(response -> {
                    player.sendMessage("Loading...");
                    // Implement the click event handling for the item buttons
                    // Add your desired logic here based on the clicked button
                })
                .closedOrInvalidResultHandler(response -> {
                    player.sendMessage("Form closed or invalid");
                });

        Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("CentoriUI23");
        assert plugin != null;
        File bdataFolder = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "bdata");
        File playerDirectory = new File(bdataFolder, playerName); // Use playerName parameter directly
        File itemsFile = new File(playerDirectory, "items.json");
        if (!playerDirectory.exists()) {
            player.sendMessage("Player directory does not exist: " + playerName);
            return;
        }

        // Check if the items file exists
        if (!itemsFile.exists()) {
            player.sendMessage("Items file does not exist: " + itemsFile.getAbsolutePath());
            return;
        }
        if (itemsFile.exists()) {
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(itemsFile)) {
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(reader);
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
                    String itemName = entry.getKey();
                    String itemDetails = entry.getValue().getAsString();

                    // Extract price and amount from the item details
                    String[] priceAmount = itemDetails.split("\\. amount ");
                    int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(priceAmount[0].split(":")[1].trim());
                    int itemAmount = Integer.parseInt(priceAmount[1].trim());

                    // Add the item as a button to the form
                    formBuilder.button(itemName + " - Price: " + itemPrice + ", Amount: " + itemAmount);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        floodgatePlayer.sendForm(formBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are sure the player used with the method is the right one? Because I don't see issue myself

Comment: Yeah im sure. I have no idea why its not working.

Comment: Can you show the first call of those method? Like part of event or command

Comment: You mean like how it starts? it starts when you join the game or type /gui. It checks if you're a bedrock player thats joining first.

Comment: Ok, and you're simply doing `CentoriUI23.getInstance().ui_screen_market(playerThatRanCommand)` ?

Comment: uh not really lol.